# Discord Command laggs

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I programmed a discord bot slots command with coins and It's working but sometimes nothing happens If I run the command. (no errors)

e.g.: you enter !slots 500 <-- these are the coins and you can win more

I tried to found the problem but I didn't found anything
Code (When the command is executed that happens)

````js
if(!coins[message.author.id]) {
        return message.channel.send("Du hast keine Coins!")
        }
let amount = args[0];
if(!amount) return message.channel.send("Du musst Coins angeben!")
let mal2 = amount * 2
let mal3 = amount * 3
let mal4 = amount * 4
let mal5 = amount * 5
let lose = amount * 1.2
let ccoins = coins[message.author.id].coins
if(ccoins < amount) return message.channel.send("Du hast nicht so viele Coins!")
if(500 < amount) return message.channel.send("Du darfst nicht mehr als 500 Coins angeben!")
    let resault = ["  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  "]
let result = Math.floor((Math.random() * resault.length))
let result2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * resault.length))
let result3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * resault.length))
if(resault[result] === "  ") {
    coins[message.author.id] = {
        coins: coins[message.author.id].coins - lose
    }
    fs.writeFile("./coins.json", JSON.stringify(coins), (err) => {
        if(err) console.log(err)
      });
      let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setAuthor(`Du hast ${lose} Coins verloren!`)
      .setDescription(`⬛️${resault[result2]}⬛️`)
      .addField(`➡️  ⬅️`, `⬛️${resault[result3]}⬛️`)
      message.channel.send(embed)
      return;
} 


        if(resault[result] === "  ") {
            coins[message.author.id] = {
                coins: coins[message.author.id].coins - lose
            }
            fs.writeFile("./coins.json", JSON.stringify(coins), (err) => {
                if(err) console.log(err)
              });
              let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
              .setAuthor(`Du hast ${lose} Coins verloren!`)
              .setDescription(`⬛️${resault[result2]}⬛️`)
              .addField(`➡️  ⬅️`, `⬛️${resault[result3]}⬛️`)
              message.channel.send(embed)
              return;
        }   
            if(resault[result] === "  ") {
                coins[message.author.id] = {
                    coins: coins[message.author.id].coins - lose
                }
                fs.writeFile("./coins.json", JSON.stringify(coins), (err) => {
                    if(err) console.log(err)
                  });
                  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                  .setAuthor(`Du hast ${lose} Coins verloren!`)
                  .setDescription(`⬛️${resault[result2]}⬛️`)
                  .addField(`➡️  ⬅️`, `⬛️${resault[result3]}⬛️`)
                  message.channel.send(embed)
                  return;
            } 
                if(resault[result] === "  ") {
                    coins[message.author.id] = {
                        coins: coins[message.author.id].coins - lose
                    }
                    fs.writeFile("./coins.json", JSON.stringify(coins), (err) => {
                        if(err) console.log(err)
                      });
                      let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                      .setAuthor(`Du hast ${lose} Coins verloren!`)
                      .setDescription(`⬛️${resault[result2]}⬛️`)
                      .addField(`➡️  ⬅️`, `⬛️${resault[result3]}⬛️`)
                      message.channel.send(embed)
                      return;
                } 



                    if(resault[result] === "  ") {
                        coins[message.author.id] = {
                            coins: amount * 3 + ccoins
                        }
                        fs.writeFile("./coins.json", JSON.stringify(coins), (err) => {
                            if(err) console.log(err)
                          });
                          let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                          .setAuthor(`Du hast ${mal3} Coins gewonnen!`)
                          .setDescription(`⬛️${resault[result2]}⬛️`)
                          .addField(`➡️  ⬅️`, `⬛️${resault[result3]}⬛️`)

                          message.channel.send(embed)
                          return;

                    }
                    if(resault[result] === "  ") {
                        coins[message.author.id] = {
                            coins: amount * 2 + ccoins
                        }
                        fs.writeFile("./coins.json", JSON.stringify(coins), (err) => {
                            if(err) console.log(err)
                          });
                          let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                          .setAuthor(`Du hast ${mal2} Coins gewonnen!`)
                          .setDescription(`⬛️${resault[result2]}⬛️`)
                          .addField(`➡️  ⬅️`, `⬛️${resault[result3]}⬛️`)
                          message.channel.send(embed)
                          return;
                    }
                    if(resault[result] === "  ") {
                        coins[message.author.id] = {
                            coins: amount * 4 + ccoins
                        }
                        fs.writeFile("./coins.json", JSON.stringify(coins), (err) => {
                            if(err) console.log(err)
                          });
                          let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                          .setAuthor(`Du hast ${mal4} Coins gewonnen!`)
                          .setDescription(`⬛️${resault[result2]}⬛️`)
                          .addField(`➡️  ⬅️`, `⬛️${resault[result3]}⬛️`)
                          message.channel.send(embed)
                          return;
                    }
                    if(resault[result] === "  ") {
                        coins[message.author.id] = {
                            coins: amount * 5 + ccoins
                        }
                        fs.writeFile("./coins.json", JSON.stringify(coins), (err) => {
                            if(err) console.log(err)
                          });
                          let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                          .setAuthor(`Du hast ${mal5} Coins gewonnen!`)
                          .setDescription(`⬛️${resault[result2]}⬛️`)
                          .addField(`➡️  ⬅️`, `⬛️${resault[result3]}⬛️`)
                          message.channel.send(embed)
                          return;

                    }




                }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So lets say `result` turns out to be a 0, `resault[result]` would then be

You do not have any check for the 3 oranges/slices. So it would just not return anything. Nor would any message send.

You also are missing checks for several more combinations. So by the looks of things 1/3 of the time your getting nothing.

Also just cuz this code is very inefficient I have a better version of this gambler here: https://jsfiddle.net/FrustratedProgrammer/19dmwL86/